# Timeout while deploying VS2010 solution to SP2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, deployment, solution-deployment, time-out

When deploy a solution (no sandbox solution) with many projects, I always get the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The
>   open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of
>   00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion
>   of a longer timeout.

On the Internet I find only one solution: Close Visual Studio, make iisreset, open Visual Studio again and deploy every single project.

Is that really the only option?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, usually that does the trick:

1. Close Visual Studio;
2. Run `iisreset.exe /noforce` on command line;
3. Open Visual Studio again;
4. Deploy every single project, one by one.

If that fails, you can also try [manually retracting the solution and redeploying afterwards](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65374616).